# how to specify the receiver address to reading the mail

Tags: php, email, pop3

I am using the below code for reading the mail using pop3 and php,but i want to specify the receiver address to the pop3 and php,i want to read the mail regarding the receiver address passed ,can any one guide me how to do it .thanks

```
<?php

    require('mime_parser.php');
    require('rfc822_addresses.php');
    require("pop3.php");

  /* Uncomment when using SASL authentication mechanisms */
    /*
    require("sasl.php");
    */

    stream_wrapper_register('mlpop3', 'pop3_stream');  /* Register the pop3 stream handler class */

    $pop3=new pop3_class;
    $pop3->hostname="xxxxxxx.com";             /* POP 3 server host name                      */
    $pop3->port=110;                         /* POP 3 server host port,
                                                usually 110 but some servers use other ports
                                                Gmail uses 995                              */
    $pop3->tls=0;                            /* Establish secure connections using TLS      */
    $user="xxxxxxx.com";                        /* Authentication user name                    */
    $password="xxxxxxxx";                    /* Authentication password                     */
    $pop3->realm="";                         /* Authentication realm or domain              */
    $pop3->workstation="";                   /* Workstation for NTLM authentication         */
    $apop=0;                                 /* Use APOP authentication                     */
    $pop3->authentication_mechanism="USER";  /* SASL authentication mechanism               */
    $pop3->debug=1;                          /* Output debug information                    */
    $pop3->html_debug=1;                     /* Debug information is in HTML                */
    $pop3->join_continuation_header_lines=1; /* Concatenate headers split in multiple lines */

    if(($error=$pop3->Open())=="")
    {
        echo "<PRE>Connected to the POP3 server &quot;".$pop3->hostname."&quot;.</PRE>\n";
        if(($error=$pop3->Login($user,$password,$apop))=="")
        {
            echo "<PRE>User &quot;$user&quot; logged in.</PRE>\n";
            if(($error=$pop3->Statistics($messages,$size))=="")
            {
                echo "<PRE>There are $messages messages in the mail box with a total of $size bytes.</PRE>\n";
                if($messages>0)
                {
                    $pop3->GetConnectionName($connection_name);
                    $message=1;
                    $message_file='mlpop3://'.$connection_name.'/'.$message;
                    $mime=new mime_parser_class;

                    /*
                    * Set to 0 for not decoding the message bodies
                    */
                    $mime->decode_bodies = 1;

                    $parameters=array(
                        'File'=>$message_file,

                        /* Read a message from a string instead of a file */
                        /* 'Data'=>'My message data string',              */

                        /* Save the message body parts to a directory     */
                        /* 'SaveBody'=>'/tmp',                            */

                        /* Do not retrieve or save message body parts     */
                            'SkipBody'=>1,
                    );
                    $success=$mime->Decode($parameters, $decoded);


                    if(!$success)
                        echo '<h2>MIME message decoding error: '.HtmlSpecialChars($mime->error)."</h2>\n";
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<h2>MIME message decoding successful</h2>'."\n";
                        echo '<h2>Message structure</h2>'."\n";
                        echo '<pre>';
                        var_dump($decoded[0]);
                        echo '</pre>';
                        if($mime->Analyze($decoded[0], $results))
                        {
                            echo '<h2>Message analysis</h2>'."\n";
                            echo '<pre>';
                            var_dump($results);
                            echo '</pre>';
                        }
                        else
                            echo 'MIME message analyse error: '.$mime->error."\n";
                    }
                }
                if($error==""
                && ($error=$pop3->Close())=="")
                    echo "<PRE>Disconnected from the POP3 server &quot;".$pop3->hostname."&quot;.</PRE>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    if($error!="")
        echo "<H2>Error: ",HtmlSpecialChars($error),"</H2>";
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "specify the receiver address to the pop3 and php"? What have you tried?

Comment: i mean i want to reterive only the email is receive from "myemail@xxxx.com"

Comment: You login using an email address, so after the login you will only retrieve emails for that address.

Comment: i am new to this can you guide me how write

Comment: I think you're on the wrong site. We don't do homeworks here.

Comment: you understand me wrongly,my email xxxx@xxx.com i am receiving more than 100 email per day.i want to retrieve the email from the specify sender like yyyy@yyy.com,can you guide me how can do that.